# Notification Center in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, cocoa-design-patterns

After programming for sometime with the iOS and Mac objective C frameworks, I have come to love the generic notification pattern implemented by the NSNotificationCenter and NSNotification classes. Coming back to C++, which has always been my language of choice for most things, I find myself trying to replicate this pattern and believe there should really already be a generic implementation of similar C++ classes offering support for it out there.

It does seem like the pattern is somewhat more difficult to implement in C++ than Objective C because of the more dynamic nature of the later, but it seems far from impossible. I've looked through the boost libraries as they are generally awesome and was sad not to find my luck there. Although the boost::bind, boost::lamda, boost::function seem like they do most of the work. Have I missed something obvious? Is there anything already existing out there that would allow me to easily replicate NSNotification/NSNotificationCenter behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried Boost.signals ?

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: With a slightly different approach, Qt has implemented "signals and slots" via a dedicated preprocessing tool (moc <-> meta object compiler). However, it is only reasonable to use it if qt ui fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @anno's recommendation to look at boot::signal, it does after examination seem like a possible option although it is, as expected, not as straight-forward as the objective C solutions. Looking through the [boost::signal tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id2850736), I thought I would go through the most relevant aspects for the problem at hand.

---

To create notification senders:

> Consider a simple news delivery service, where clients connect to a news provider that then sends news to all connected clients as information arrives. The news delivery service may be constructed like this:

```
class NewsItem { /* ... */ };
boost::signal<void (const NewsItem&)> deliverNews;
```

The objective of `deliverNews` is to inform observers that a `NewsItem` has been generated.

---

Observers can be added as follows (using the boost::bind library):

> Clients that wish to receive news updates need only connect a function object that can receive news items to the deliverNews signal. For instance, we may have a special message area in our application specifically for news, e.g.,:

```
struct NewsMessageArea : public MessageArea
{
public:
  // ...

  void displayNews(const NewsItem& news) const
  {
    messageText = news.text();
    update();
  }
};

// ...
NewsMessageArea newsMessageArea = new NewsMessageArea(/* ... */);
// ...
deliverNews.connect(boost::bind(&NewsMessageArea::displayNews, newsMessageArea, _1));
```

---

To address the problem of removing observers which have been deallocated from the list, boost::signal offers the following solution

> However, what if the user closes the news message area, destroying the
>   newsMessageArea object that deliverNews knows about? Most likely, a
>   segmentation fault will occur. However, with Boost.Signals one need
>   only make NewsMessageArea trackable, and the slot involving
>   newsMessageArea will be disconnected when newsMessageArea is
>   destroyed. The NewsMessageArea class is made trackable by deriving
>   publicly from the boost::signals::trackable class, e.g.:

```
struct NewsMessageArea : public MessageArea, public boost::signals::trackable
{
  // ...
};
```

> At this time there is a significant limitation to the use of trackable
>   objects in making slot connections: function objects built using
>   Boost.Bind are understood, such that pointers or references to
>   trackable objects passed to boost::bind will be found and tracked.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you could create a class that has a vector of function pointers to call when a certain notification is called - A class that has a dictionary where the objects are the vectors of functions to call when a notification is pushed

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `boost` packages mentioned in other answers, another option is [`poco::NotificationCenter`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/package-Foundation.Notifications.html).

This implementation is closer to the Cocoa notification framework, as specifically discussed on Poco's [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationCenter.html):

> The NotificationCenter class is basically a C++ implementation of the
>   NSNotificationCenter class found in Apple's Cocoa (or OpenStep).